# Return count of customer from SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following code that when executed will return the count of customers that arrvied during the given month within the parameter. However, during the code being executed I recieve runtime error 3021 (No current record). Where is it exactly that I am going wrong?

```
Public Function CountOfcustomer(RequiredDate As Date)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

       strSQL = "SELECT Format([dateArrived]," & Chr(34) & "mm\yyyy" & Chr(34) & ") AS reportDate, Count(CalibrationLog.customer) AS CountOfcustomer " & _
            "From CalibrationLog " & _
            "GROUP BY Format([dateArrived]," & Chr(34) & "mm\yyyy" & Chr(34) & ") " & _
            "HAVING (((Format([dateArrived]," & Chr(34) & "mm\yyyy" & Chr(34) & "))= Format(" & RequiredDate & "," & Chr(34) & "mm\yyyy" & Chr(34) & ") ));"


    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    CountOfcustomer = rst!CountOfcustomer

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Shown in the Immediate window;

```
SELECT Format([dateArrived],"mm\yyyy") AS reportDate, Count(CalibrationLog.customer) AS CountOfcustomer 
From CalibrationLog 
GROUP BY Format([dateArrived],"mm\yyyy") 
HAVING (((Format([dateArrived],"mm\yyyy"))= Format(12/02/2020,"mm\yyyy") ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to retrieve a count for the month of your date argument, `RequiredDate`.

Looks to me like it could be simpler to avoid all that `Format()` stuff.  You don't even need to do it as a `GROUP BY` query.  Just ask for a `Count` with a `WHERE` clause which selects only those rows which fall within your target date range ... and compare dates as dates instead of dates transformed to strings.

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "PARAMETERS RequiredDate Date; " & _
    "SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfcustomer FROM CalibrationLog " & _
    "WHERE [dateArrived] >= DateSerial(Year(RequiredDate), Month(RequiredDate), 1) " & _
    "AND [dateArrived] < DateSerial(Year(RequiredDate), Month(RequiredDate) + 1, 1);"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
qdf.Parameters("RequiredDate").Value = RequiredDate
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
    CountOfcustomer = rst!CountOfcustomer
End If
```

With this approach, Access can use an index on that `dateArrived` field to quickly identify which records satisfy the query's `WHERE` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You should validate in the function that you probably don't receive any record in the Recordset.

```
CountOfcustomer = rst!CountOfcustomer
```

If no customer arrived in the specified RequiredDate, you can't do `rst!CountOfcustomer`

Comment: I do agree with this, however, on the date given during testing ie 12.02.2020 the function should be returning a count of 15 customers, but instead throws the error message stated above.

Comment: @Shadyjunior did you debug this? How does the strSQL looks like before using it to open the recordset?
Maybe the date being sent has a format that's not recognized by SQL to Format

Comment: I have added the debug.print statement to the OP

Comment: @Shadyjunior I think we have two issues there. First, SQL uses single quotes (') instead of double quotes (").
On the other hand, I think you're missing the quotes that wrap strings in SQL in the Format of the date you send as parameter.
Format(12/02/2020,"mm\yyyy")
this should be
Format('12/02/2020', 'mm\yyyy')